# implementation of traits with stl containers

Tags: c++, stl, containers, traits

I have a question concerning implementation of traits with stl containers.

I have some code which should work with different objects (with tensors in my case) and I have no direct access to tensor class (for instance when I use external tensor library). I try to realize all necessary properties of tensors through traits.

For example, I have a template class which should works with tensor:

```
template<typename Traits>
class Operator{
  typedef typename Traits::state_t state_t;
  .........
};
```

It means that for a particular tensor type I should specify its own traits type. For instance for `SomeTensor` I do:

```
class SomeTensorTraits{
  typedef SomeTensor state_t;
  .........
};
```

When I want to use other tensor type I just write another traits:

```
class OtherTensorTraits{
  typedef OtherTensor state_t;
  .........
};
```

Then I use a different tensor types in the same `Operator` code and it works fine.

Problems start when I want to collect a different tensors to some stl container (std::vector for example). I remind you that I don't have an access to tensor classes (so I can not make tensors derived from some base class) and I also don't want to collect `TensorTraits` in the container.

Thus the question is how to collect different `Tensor` objects through implementation of tensors in helper traits?

Appreciate your help.

Comment: Are you asking how to store different types in the same vector? Doesn't work.

Comment: Maybe `boost::variant<SomeTensor,OtherTensor,etc>`;

Comment: Thanks for your answers. 
No, I don't ask how to store different types in vector. I ask how to write some wrapper or trick how to avoid it an without direct access to types.

Using <code>boost::variant</code> is not ok, because in this case by adding new tensors types you should rewrite class with container.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `boost::any` to encapsulate objects.
Other way (more dirty) is to use a union that covers all cases.

Also you can create `IOperator` class, derive from it and use `vector<IOperator&>` for storing references.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Definitely I don't want cover all cases. So I need some general. I also don't want use boost because I'm going to use my code as a part of more general math library and it doesn't use boost. But your idea with references looks great. Can you explain it in more details?

Comment: You define your Operator class like that: `template<typename Traits>
class Operator : public IOperator{ ... }`. You also define IOperator class with public pure virtual methods you want to have access and you define methods in Operator class that overloads those pure virtual methods. Remember that vector will store references, so objects must be have lifetime of container. Possibly dynamic allocation and `std::share_ptr` will be better for it.

Comment: But I don't want to collect different operators. I want to collect tensors.
And if I use reference to tensor in any case there is problem with different types. Just because reference class also defined as `code` template<typename Traits>`/code`. Or may be I didn't got your idea.

Comment: Well you need it make one base class with common interface above this template class. Then you can store references to those base in a vector. Also your operator code should interact with interface provided by base class.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want generic traits with specialization:

```
template<typename T>
struct TensorTraits;

template<>
struct TensorTraits<SomeTensor>;
{
    using state_t = SomeTensor;
    // ...
};

template<>
struct TensorTraits<OtherTensor>
{
    using state_t = OtherTensor state_t;
};
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. How can I store `Tensors` in container then? I actually want to write some class which will be responsible for it. Like that: `class Collect{ std::vector<?> coll;};`. Can you give me details of your idea?